# Secure store url with store code in CMS page or block

Tags: multistore, cms, magento-1.6, secure

How can I get **secure** store url **with** store code in **CMS** page or block?

e.g. https://www.mydomain.com/storecode/ should be generated..

Comment: do you have store codes in url enabled on your magento instance?

Comment: Are you talking about Admin setting? If so, how do I check that?

Comment: yes I'm talking about the admin setting. Check by looking int he admin: System->Configuration->web

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="" _secure=1}}">Some text</a>
```

if that does not work try

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="" _force_secure=1}}">Some text</a>
```

Comment: @user17126. Welcome to SE. when an answer solves your problem mark it as accepted. This way future readers with the same problem find the answer faster.

Comment: I think it's _forced_secure=1, app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php line 135

Answer (score 0):

For the unsecured base URL:

```
{{config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}
```

Or for the secured base URL:

```
{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}
```